# extjs 3 store load new records while keeping previous

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I'm using a store to load data into a dataview tpl. The desired behavior is when user scrolls down to bottom, new records are loaded while previous remain there.

I've Already Tried This:
[How to load additional records into the store/keep previous while loading new ones](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?156466-How-to-load-additional-records-into-the-store-keep-previous-while-loading-new-ones)

But the above mentioned solution is not working for me as i'm trying to use it in ExtJS 3.
Is there any solution for ExtJS 3.4?

NB: I'm loading store every time user scrolls down to bottom by `store.load();`

Comment: check `store.load` method's `add` param e.g.`store.load({add:true})` [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-load)

Comment: Thanks @MMT you made my day. Submit your comment as an answer so that i accept it as answer. This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `store.load` method's `add` param, 
which is Indicator to append loaded records rather than replace the current cache. 
e.g.`store.load({add:true})`

refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-load)